# How do I best simulate a 80386?

Tags: software-recommendation, 80386, simulator

I have used emu8086 to simulate the Intel 8086 before.

I like that it allows me to view the opcodes, the data in the registers in a very user friendly way.

[image]

What simulators are available for the 80386?

I have tried using DOSBox. It seems quite promising, but it seems generic and simulates for DOS. Am I missing something?

More specifically, I want to write programs for the 80386 - a simple system program and a simple applications program.

Comment: What did your web research reveal? And why do the findings not satisfy your requirements?

Comment: What is best for you depends on what you want to emulate and why. Would you mind expanding the question a bit.

Comment: @thebusybee I came across DOSBox and actually ran some old games, but I want to be able to write a simple OS for 80386. I edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: @Justme I hope I made the question a bit clearer. Say I want to write an OS specifically for the 80386, how would I go about that. DOSBox (the nearest thing I saw to what I want) seems specialized only for old games. But say I want to create a simplified OS and a simple program running on that OS, how would I go on?

Comment: Perhaps a better question would be: what kind of features are you looking for in the simulator you seek? Myself, for OS and bootloader development, I use QEMU paired with GDB; if I were to target the 80386 specifically, I guess I would have simply used the `-march=i386` for GCC, `cpu 386` for NASM, then after I got it working in QEMU, cross-checked it in a more faithful emulator like PCem. Good enough for me, but not too beginner-friendly.

Answer (score 16):

I don’t know about “best”, but [Bochs](https://bochs.sourceforge.io/) includes a good debugger; here’s its most basic UI:

[image: Screenshot of the X Bochs debugger]

Other UI variants exist.

Note that Bochs emulates a Pentium MMX or later; it can’t be configured to specifically emulate an 80386. Nevertheless, it is very well suited to operating system development, and if you configure your build tools to only produce 80386 code you can be reasonably confident that the result is 80386-compatible.

Depending on what you’re trying to do exactly, [DOSBox-X](https://dosbox-x.com/) may also be an option; this includes a debugger, terminal-based on Linux:

[image: Screenshot of the in-terminal DOSBox-X debugger]

This can be set to emulate a 386 specifically:

[image: Screenshot DOSBox-X CPU type menu]

Comment: Does anyone know if PCem, 86Box, or VARCem have a similar debugger? I haven't had time to set any of them up since they started gaining Linux support, but I understand that lineage of x86 emulators aims to reproduce the hardware they emulate much more accurately than DOSBox and its descendants (to the point that VARCem bills itself as cycle-accurate) and 86box lists support for emulating a "POST card" or "ISABugger" (I'm not sure what the difference is) with output in the window's status bar.

Comment: They don’t have anything similar as far as I’m aware. ISABugger is useful to debug code running inside 86box but it’s not a debugger in the typical sense and AFAIK it requires code changes to the software being debugged. (Incidentally, PCem at least had supported Linux for a long time!)

Comment: @ssokolow Last I checked, PCem does not support any debugging. 86Box supports the GDB protocol at least, so you can use any debugger that understands that. Never heard of VARCem.

Comment: @user3840170 have you tried 86Box with the GDB protocol? How does it deal with segmentation?

Comment: I don’t think I managed to run it, actually. Looking up the source code now, [GDB (i.e. the client) is presented with the linear (virtual) address space](https://github.com/86Box/86Box/blob/824721b050aa6d8335e9c0eb27dd0ee25bf21069/src/gdbstub.c#L836-L856) and segment bases are not separately exposed. So the short answer seems to be ‘not well’.

Comment: @StephenKitt your DOSBox seems to have a menu. Mine doesn't. What version is it?

Comment: @David it’s not DOSBox, it’s DOSBox-X; see the link in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a modern x86-64 system, you may just need a user-friendly debugger, depending what kinds of programs you want to debug.  A 32-bit process can run natively under a modern 64-bit OS, and a good debugger will show disassembly and registers.  (And modern 32-bit mode is still compatible with 386).

See the bottom of [SO's x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for asm debugging tips on Windows and Linux.

Of course you'd be running in 32-bit compat mode in ring 3, so you can't access hardware directly, and the system-call interfaces are different from DOS and BIOS.  e.g. under Linux, `mov eax, 1` / `int 0x80` to make an `_exit` system call.

Comment: There are enough peculiarities at the hardware level that modern 32-bit code is _not quite_ 80386 compatible even if limited to just opcodes available on the 80386. Certain execution semantics differ enough to matter, though this is generally not visible from ring 3 (however, this is a lot of why the Linux kernel only supports 80486 and newer CPUs these days when running on 32-bit x86).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn: Yeah, it really depends why someone wants a 386 simulator; if they just wanted to be able to single-step normal 32-bit code, use a debugger in user-space.  I debated just posting a comment instead of answer, but figured the OP (and maybe future readers) might just be looking for a UI like emu8086 for learning 32-bit mode.  It's not like emu8086 accurately simulates an 8086 or IBM-PC either (e.g. you can't hook interrupts, IIRC, and allows some 186 stuff).  If you truly want 80386 specifically, then yeah DOSBox or Bochs are good bets.  (Or just full-system legacy BIOS mode).